# How to write truncate table query in shell script file

Tags: shell, unix, google-bigquery, scripting, informatica-cloud

I want to place the shell script file on Unix server. This file i will be using in iics command task.The file should truncate the table from big query.

Shell scripting syntax to truncate the big query table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gcloud` [cli](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) in your `Shell` script, example :

```bash
bq query  --use_legacy_sql=false \
      'TRUNCATE TABLE `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`'
```

`bq` `query` allows to execute a query.